# Join CSV and shapefile in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I am new to QGIS and using version 3.0. I have written below code to join population data with Building Layer. I am using Python Console within QGIS.
I didn't get any error but the target files doesn't show update on fields.
I need to join `FID_1` field of CSV file with `FID` field in shapefile.

```
vectorLyr=QgsVectorLayer("C:/Test/demand/Demand.shp", "BuildingLayer", "ogr")
vectorLyr.isValid()
uri='file:///C:/Test/data.csv?delimiter=,'
infoLyr=QgsVectorLayer(uri,'Population', 'delimitedtext')
infoLyr.isValid()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLyr)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(infoLyr)
info=QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
info.joinLayerId=infoLyr.id()
info.joinFieldName="FID_1"
info.targetFieldName="FID"
info.memoryCache=True
vectorLyr.addJoin(info)

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vectorLyr,"C:/Test/joinedata.shp", "CP1250", vectorLyr.crs(), "ESRI ShapeFile")
joinedabcLyr=QgsVectorLayer("C:/Test/joinedata.shp", "joinedata", "ogr")
joinedabcLyr.isValid()
vectorLyr.dataProvider().fields().count()
joinedabcLyr.dataProvider().fields().count()
```

There are 10 fields in shapefile and 4 in the CSV, but even after joining Target Object shows 10 fields instead of 14 fields.

Comment: @kadir can you help please ?

Answer (score 3):

The below solution is working fine in QGIS 3.0

```
vectorLyr=QgsVectorLayer("C:/Test/dema/Demand.shp","BuildingLayer","ogr")
vectorLyr.isValid()
uri='file:///C:/Test/data.csv?delimiter=,'
infoLyr=QgsVectorLayer(uri,'Population','delimitedtext')
infoLyr.isValid()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLyr)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(infoLyr)
csvField='FID_1'
shpField='FID'
joinObject=QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.setJoinFieldName(csvField)
joinObject.setTargetFieldName(shpField)
joinObject.setJoinLayerId(infoLyr.id())
joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject.setJoinLayer(infoLyr)
vectorLyr.addJoin(joinObject)
```