# qgis:JoinAttributeTable is giving a Syntax Error in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I am new to QGIS 3.0 and using "qgis:Joinattributetable" for joining .csv and .shp file. Below is my code, but I am getting Syntax Error.

```
AttributeError: module Processing has no attribute 'runandLoadResults'
```

I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

```
vectorLyr=QgsVectorLayer("C:/Test/demand/Demand.shp","BuildingLayer","ogr")
vectorLyr.isValid()
uri='file:///C:/Test/data.csv?delimiter=,'
infoLyr=QgsVectorLayer(uri,'Population','delimitedtext')
infoLyr.isValid()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLyr)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(infoLyr)
shpField='FID_1'
csvField='FID'
result=processing.runandLoadResults('qgis:joinattributetable',vectorLyr,infoLyr,shpField,csvField,None)
```

Comment: @snaileater can yo help in this ?

Comment: [@ps1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/125097/ps1), can you please show us the `Syntax Error` that you end up with.

Comment: AttributeError: module Processing has no attribute 'runandLoadResults'

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins_pyqgis.html I am taking help of this and trying to join both data in Qgis3

Comment: @Taras I corrected it to processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:joinattributetable',vectorLyr,infoLyr,shpField,csvField,None) , but now i am getting runAndLoadResults() takes from 2 to 4 positional Arguments but 6 were given. please help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you need to modify your `result` because you misspelt it.

Secondly, `.runAndLoadResults()` takes only two parameters. In your case, the first one looks right and the second is wrong because it should be a dictionary with the necessary parameters.

Try this:

```
result = processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:joinattributestable', parameters)
```

Hint: Set up your **parameters = {}**.

```
parameters = {'INPUT': vectorLyr,
              'JOIN': infoLyr,
...
}
```

And check these references as well:

- [Using processing algorithms from the console](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html)
- [Using processing.runandload in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261896/using-processing-runandload-in-qgis-3)
- [Optional parameters in QGIS Processing scripts & models](https://anitagraser.com/tag/processing/)
- [PyQGIS 101: Running Processing tools](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-running-processing-tools/)

Comment: Now i am getting module "processing" has no attribute runandload.

Comment: Pay attention to the [reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261896/using-processing-runandload-in-qgis-3), where it says that `processing.runandload()` is for QGIS <= 2.18. Since you are deploying QGIS 3.0 you should use `processing.runAndLoadResults()`.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294406/join-csv-and-shapefile-in-pyqgis Can you see this and let me know what is wrong? I am using runandLoad as an alternative

Comment: I already corrected that runAndLoadResults, but not sure how to write Parameter List

Comment: Do not afraid to try and check QGIS documentation!

Comment: I tried ,even wrote the paramater List , but still unable to get. :( And i am more confused now . https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294406/join-csv-and-shapefile-in-pyqgis  I tried this still not getting required output

Comment: @ps1 You may try to look at this link for the field names: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributesbylocation